# ViewBag Memory Leaks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, garbage-collection

I have a function that creates a list of objects and return it to be stored in the ViewBag.

The code will look like:

```
List<XDocument> xDocs = readXmlFiles(path);// a "new List<XDocument>()" is called
ViewBag.data = xDocs;
return View();
```

My question is, if we have the code as this, will the garbage collector release the allocated resources for the xDocs or not? or at least will it be freed once a new request for the same view is processed?

Comment: Yes it will release it but it has not to be when a new request is done it can be later

Comment: this is not a research question but a general query. Read a little more on MVC.

Comment: @NewtonSheikh, thanks, and yes I should do my homework more than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, if we have the code as this, will the garbage
>   collector release the allocated resources for the xDocs or not?

Yes, it will release it. The `ViewBag` will be eligible for garbage collection as soon as the request has finished executing.

> or at least will it be freed once a new request for the same view is processed?

The exact timing of when the garbage collection occurs is out of your control. The CLR will choose the best suitable moment to perform it. This could happen before or after the next request. Since you are creating a new collection for each request this collection will be eligible for garbage collection once there are no longer any references to it (i.e. once the request has finished executing).

Comment: What about the lists, there are items there, is it necessary to clear the lists or not?

Comment: Since the list is the only object that is holding references to those objects, once ViewBag is eligible for garbage collection, all its properties will be eligible for garbage collection including this list and since the list is eligible for garbage collection and the only reference to those objects, they will also be eligible for garbage collection.